# How to hide shadow-copies in NFS shares?

Tags: samba, nfs, vss, files

I have a Ubuntu server with both samba and nfs-server.

The server does snapshotting for the exported directory
and the samba server uses the snapshots to emulate
shadow copies. ( vfs objects = shadow_copy )

When I export the same directory via NFS, the clients
see the snapshot directories. Thus, a NFS client gets
a messed-up directory listing containing lots of
entries like @GMT-2012.01.31-13.00.01

How can I hide those subdirectories from NFS clients?

Thanks!

Comment: How much control do you have over the NFS clients?

Comment: What is doing the 'snapshotting' ?

Comment: I have full control over the NFS clients. Snapshotting is done with [btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#Subvolumes_and_snapshots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more of a hindsight suggestion, but in general you should place snapshots of directory `dir` residing in a `parentdir` in `parentdir` or in subdirectory of `parentdir`, not in `dir`. So that you'd have directory hierarchy similar to this:

```
parentdir
├── dir
│   ├── Apps
│   └── Clients
└── snapshots
    ├── @GMT-2012.01.30-13.00.01
    │   ├── Apps
    │   └── Clients
    └── @GMT-2012.01.31-13.00.01
        ├── Apps
        └── Clients
```

`shadow_copy2` from Samba does support setting where the directory with snapshots resides, so you can redirect it to `parentdir/snapshots`, like this:

```
[share]
...
path = parentdir/dir
vfs object = shadow_copy2
shadow:snapdir = parentdir/snapshot
shadow:basedir = parentdir/dir
```

or if you want to export `Apps` from the above example as a share, then you can use configuration like this:

```
[Apps]
...
path = parentdir/dir/Apps
vfs object = shadow_copy2
shadow:snapdir = parentdir/snapshot
shadow:basedir = parentdir/dir
```

Comment: Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you'll be able to get what you want.